# Test Class Error in salesforce

Tags: code-coverage

I have a Batch class:

```
global class updateCusotmerMasterData implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful,Database.AllowsCallouts
{
    public updateCusotmerMasterData(){}
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id,iCustomer__c  from account where ID NOT IN (Select Account__c from DetailSet__c)]);
        //return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,iCustomer__c from Account where Icustomer__c ='00BE01 Approval UAT10']);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> Acc)
    {
        list<String> Icustomer = new list<string>();
        for(account Acc1 : Acc)
        {
            Icustomer.add(Acc1.iCustomer__c);
        }
        HTTPSclass.HTTPSclass1(Icustomer);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Test Class:

@isTest

```
public class TestupdateCusotmerMasterData 
{
    static testmethod void test()
    {
        list<Account> TestAcc = new list<Account>();
        for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) 
        {
            account acc = new account();
            acc.Name='account'+i;
            acc.iCustomer__c = 'aaa'+i;
            acc.PG_JnJCustomerCode__c='aaa'+i;
            acc.PG_AccountGuid__c='aaa'+i;
            TestAcc.add(acc);
        }
        insert TestAcc; 
        Test.startTest();
        updateCusotmerMasterData UpdateCustomer = new updateCusotmerMasterData();
        Database.executeBatch(UpdateCustomer);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

While Running Test Class it is showing error like:
**Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts**  How to Rectify the error Guide me for the Answer

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you cannot do webservice callouts in a test method. In order to test those webservice callouts, you need to utilise HttpCalloutMock. You can refer to this page for reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html

Comment: There is all kinds of sample code. Do some legwork and search for it. It's easy to find even in the link provided.

Comment: Follow the link or do a search of your own. It's in the docs...